# Backtesting vs live trading data handling and abstraction

Tags: backtesting, historical-data, database

I'm an individual trying to build a trading system which will ideally be eventually scalable to 1-15 second resolution intraday trading strategies. I'm having some trouble understanding the difference between data feeds applied to a backtest and data feeds applied to live trading and I have a few specific questions:

**Are backtests and live trading typically built upon the same abstraction or operate on the same trading/processing engine?**

My first thought is that they are, since they should ideally operate identically for backtesting accuracy and realism

**Do live data feeds and historic datasets typically provide an identical interface in their respective handlers for querying/retrieving their datasets?**

The current state of my system only runs on historic data for backtests with the trading engine updating the time step of the data handler itself. This doesn't seem like a viable solution for higher frequency real time data since it relies on the trading engine to update the data feed rather than the data feed handler. After some research, it seems like a query-based mechanism would be more suitable for real time data since it gives data management control to the handler. Though I'm having trouble understanding how static historical data could be loaded into data stream to be processed in an identical way.

**How are data streams most effectively processed?**

Under the assumption that both historical data and live data are fed into event streams. I'm having trouble understanding how those streams are then made to be queried or otherwise predictably retrievable by the trading engine. A time series database seems to make the most sense purely due to its ability to handle the volume of data and store enough lookback data, but most time series databases though are fairly expensive for an individual, and I'm not sure it's the most cost effective way of processing the volume of data. What other options are there for providing an effective query engine for both historical and live data feeds?

I'm probably a bit out of my depth here since I'm still fairly new to this, so please tell me if I'm taking the wrong approach to this. I'd also love some more info as to how these systems are designed, or any other resources/books to read regarding data handling methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I recommend making historical backtests and live trading as similar as possible. This leaves you one lesser source of variability when you inevitably see different backtest and live results.

> Do live data feeds and historic datasets typically provide an identical interface in their respective handlers for querying/retrieving their datasets?

> Are backtests and live trading typically built upon the [...] operate on the same trading/processing engine?

These are two different things. Both are important.

Having the same interface lets you reuse the same code for both backtest and production. Arguably, this is slightly more important because:

- Most strategies are very complex state machines, and it is very difficult to implement the same strategy twice over with two different sets of interfaces.
- At some point upstream, it is nearly impossible to use the exact same "processing engine" for backtest and production anyway since the former reads from a file while the latter reads off a multicast/unicast subscription, and the former spends most of the time waiting while the latter can keep reading. I've seen some firms go to extreme lengths to do unify the two, even making their backtesting platform replay whole packet captures just to backtest 1 symbol, with insubstantial benefits.
- The purpose of a "backtest" is not necessarily to get accurate metrics like PnL, and there could be many other goals which cause you to design your backtest loop (presumably a major part of your "processing engine") to prioritize speed (throughput) over accuracy, or parallelism over serial processing, async over synchronous etc.

> How are data streams most effectively processed?

See my other posts on databases.

Comment: Thanks this is super helpful! A couple followup questions if you don't mind.
Your previous posts about databases generally suggest that they're not needed, is this true only for backtesting or is it also true for live trading? In live trading the temporary persistence and querying ability would suggest that a OLAP database like Clickhouse that you mentioned would be ideal, but is there another practical way of analyzing the streaming data at scale?

Comment: That is also true for live trading. Chances are that the window of data you need is small and you can simply persist that window in-memory if you need to persist more than the last data point. If you need recovery of that window if the system crashes, you could either duplicate the socket/stream buffer upstream and have another "out-of-band" piece that asynchronous dumps that, or even have your downstream application itself asynchronously dump or serialize its entire history to disk if you just want a hacky solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Are backtests and live trading typically built upon the same abstraction or operate on the same trading/processing engine?

It could be the case, and I see many projects allow to live trade backtested strategies.

My opinion - we can achieve more if we separate the two and build more specific abstractions for each.

The goal of backtest is to be fast to run, easy to use. So we can test more strategies, quantity over quality.

The live trader has to be safe, reliable, provide monitoring, record activities.
Safe - it should detect anomalies (large orders rate, big loss, significant increase in trading volume, etc.), stop runaway trades.
Reliable - should have strategies to overcome network outages, gracefully handle errors, etc.

About abstractions and how they can help. One example I recently was working on: in backtest we can rid of orders and just adjust position. Instead of order -> transaction -> position adjustment, we can do position adjustment -> transaction.

So we can start using different language:

```
buy -> add to position
sell -> reduce position
trade -> session (trading session)
close trade -> close session (a side effect of adjusting position to 0)
order(market) -> transaction (a side effect for position change)
order(limit, stop_loss) -> brackets
```

For me, it makes it easier to write a strategy. And it does not hurt the backtest result, as backtest results are far from perfect anyway. For the live trader, we will have to deal with orders.

> How are data streams most effectively processed?

Keep it simple, I just store in csv files (500 rows per block), like this: https://github.com/nanvel/cipher-bt/blob/master/cipher/sources/binance_spot_ohlc.py#L49

A benefit of this is the simplicity of loading it into pandas:

```python
df = pd.concat(
    (pd.read_csv(p) for p in paths), ignore_index=True
).drop_duplicates(subset=["ts"])
```

> I'd also love some more info as to how these systems are designed, or any other resources/books to read regarding data handling methods.

I haven't seen any good technical book on it, I imagine it will be fairly boring with a lot of code examples, and those code examples are usually low quality.

Check Quantitative Trading by Ernest P. Chan

Fun read: The Man Who Solved the Market by Gregory Zuckerman